# when I click a UIButton I'm trying to find out which cells are currently selected inside a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have 2 `UITableViews`.  When I click the `UIButton` outside of either `UITableView` I'm trying to determine which cells are selected in each tableview.

Anyone have a good way of doing this?  Would I loop over the cells to determine which cell is currently selected?  Or is there already a method that can tell me?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You will have to loop over the cells and check if they are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Take a look at `UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference`

[UITableViewDelege Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

EDIT: When the user select a row in one of your tables you can get it using this method and a couple of variables for the table and the cell and then you can pass what you got as soon as the user tap on your button.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    thisIsMyTable = tableView;
    thisIsTheSelectedRow = indexPath.row;
    }

- (void)buttonTapped {
    // Do what you need
}
```

Comment: To be clear this function will get fired when the user taps any cell. Therefore you will need to keep track of the selected cells another way. The documentation link provided mentions that you should use checkboxes to keep track of selected state. http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9-SW6

Comment: The button I am clicking is outside of the UITableView ... so that method wouldn't work in this case.  Thanks though.

Comment: Ah ... good idea!  Never thought about doing that.  Geez!  =)  Thanks!!